# getting unique digits from a specific integer

Tags: c

Hello so i need to create a function in C that enables one  to get how many  unique digits are inside a number example: 1224553.
the desired output would be : 
" there are 5 unique digits , they are as follow, 5 3 2 4 1" Thus a unique number when displaying shouldn't repeat itself and i'm stuck at achieving that. this is my code for the function. 
outcome should be as the following : 
example : 13454
There is/are 4 unique digit(s)
The unique digit(s) would be
1
3
4
5

Comment: Time to use a debugger.

Comment: Time to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @rohankishibe  Why is 0 excluded from the counted digits     if (tmp != 0)
      array1[counter] = tmp; ?

Comment: in the first `for` loop you probably want to modify the value of `val`, i.e. `val /= 10`

Comment: Or handle the digits are characters after `sprintf (buf, "%d", your_int);`